# Pagination on sql fetched row in php

Tags: php

I want to use pagination on sql fetched row. I am using this code:

```
     <?php
      $rec_limit = 4;

     $sql = "SELECT count(id) FROM wp_wct8 ";
     $retval = mysql_query( $sql);
     if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
     $rec_count = $row[0];
    if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) ) {
        $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
        $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
     }else {
        $page = 0;
        $offset = 0;
     }



     $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);


       $sql = "SELECT id, name, insurance ". 
        "FROM wp_wct8 ".
        "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

     $retval = mysql_query( $sql);
     if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
     }

    while ($b = mysql_fetch_array($retval)){
    echo $b['name'];
    echo $b['insurance'];

    }
    if( $page > 0 ) {
        $last = $page - 2;
        echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $last\">Last 4 Records</a> |";
        echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $page\">Next 4 Records</a>";
     }else if( $page == 0 ) {
        echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $page\">Next 4 Records</a>";
     }else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit ) {
        $last = $page - 2;
        echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $last\">Last 4 Records</a>";
     }
      ?>
```

but pagination not working... when i click on show next 4 records it is showing same records not next..please helpme... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to put this code online as it's vulnerable to SQL injection. (Use prepared statements with PDO instead or at least, escape your input in the SQL query.)

I assume the error are the whitespaces in your links. So try removing the whitespaces, e.g. `echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 4 Records</a> |";`